# Octave - compare matrix's columns with vector

Tags: vector, matrix, equals, octave

I have a matrix and a vector and I want to compare each column of the matrix with vector - what i want to get is the number of the column that is equal to vector.
Example:

```
matrix M=1 1 0 1
         1 0 0 0
         0 1 1 0

vector v= 1 0 1
```

the result should be 2 (since second column of M is equal to vector v)

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
octave> M = [1 1 0 1; 1 0 0 0; 0 1 1 0];
octave> v = [1 0 1];
octave> sum(M == repmat(v', 1, 4))
ans =

   1   3   2   2

octave> sum(M == repmat(v', 1, 4)) == size(M, 1)
ans =

   0   1   0   0

octave> find(sum(M == repmat(v', 1, 4)) == size(M, 1))
ans =  2
```

Comment: @user1926550: works fine here. Please post the actual error message.

Comment: after sum(M == v') I get:
error: mx_el_eq: nonconformat arguments (op1 is 3x4, op2 is 3x1)

error: evaluating argument list element number 1

error: evaluating argument list element number 1

Comment: @user1926550: it looks like broadcasting was removed in newer versions of Octave. What if you try `sum(M == repmat(v', 1, 4))`?

Comment: yeah that works.
I tried your first solution on newer version of Octave and it works fine.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

use broadcasting (`bsxfun`), to compare the vector to each of the rows in the matrix. Then `find` which row is `all` true

```
find (all (bsxfun (@eq, m, v')))
```